# Error: could not send: EOF on instantiating chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am getting

> Error: could not send: EOF

on instantiating chaincode in HF. I followed the correct steps for installing binaries, images etc.

After installation I used following command in the **first-network** directory to install and instantiate chaincode:

```
./byfn.sh generate
./byfn.sh up
docker exec -it cli bash
peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/fabcar/javascript -l node
```

On executing last command this is the output that I got:

```
2019-03-28 09:22:04.047 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-03-28 09:22:04.048 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
2019-03-28 09:22:04.950 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 003 Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
```

then I used the command to instantiate chaincode which is:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -n fabcar -v 1.0 -C mychannel -c '{"Args":[]}' -l node
```

And the output was an error like this:

```
2019-03-28 09:23:25.743 UTC [chaincodeCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Retrieved channel (mychannel) orderer endpoint: orderer.example.com:7050
2019-03-28 09:23:25.747 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default escc
2019-03-28 09:23:25.747 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default vscc
Error: could not send: EOF
```

I think I missed something but I am not sure.
Can anyone tell where I went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i see you are using node chaincode, but you have not mentioned "-l node" while instantiating. you have to mention that. refer https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html#install-instantiate-chaincode

Comment: Sorry, I used it in command but forgot to mention here. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 14):

I found that adding the TLS certificate options to the instantiate command worked for me. I am using Golang for my chaincode language

Install: (for reference)

```
peer chaincode install \
  -n mycc \
  -v 1.0 \
  -p myorg/chaincode
```

Instantiate:

```
peer chaincode instantiate \
  -C mychannel \
  -n mycc \
  -v 1.0 \
  -c '{"Args":["wallet","123"]}' \
  --tls true \
  --cafile /myorg/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/myorg.org/orderers/orderer.myorg.org/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.myorg.org-cert.pem
```

I didn't have to specify the following options though including them did not break anything:

```
-P "OR ('MYORGMSP.peer')" \
-l golang \
```

I changed the CLI container to mount my crypto material at `/myorg/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto-config` which differs from the default location used by other examples.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me!